# How do OpenCL platforms are listed for OpenCL-2.0 devices?

Tags: opencl, version, platform

I need to implement a truly working platform version filter targeted to version **1.2** for my open-source project:
https://github.com/tugrul512bit/Cekirdekler

I don't have 150$ to buy an OpenCL2.0 capable graphics card for now so I'm working on a pure-1.2 version system and not sure about other (new)systems.

**Question:** How does a list of platforms looks like when there are only opencl 2.0 capable gpus and both 1.2(max) and 2.0(max) capable gpus exist in same system?

Lets assume I'm using this

```
clGetPlatformIDs()
```

to get a list. Should I suppose it gives only single version platforms per device or,

For example, a GTX-Titan XP(opencl 2.0 capable?) can list two platforms:

- OpenCL 1.2
- OpenCL 2.0

separately for same device? Or it just gives 2.0 version?

What about a GTX-TitanXP and a GT-640?

- OpenCL 1.2 (TitanXP + GT-640)
- OpenCL 2.0 (TitanXP)

or

- OpenCL 2.0 (TitanXP)
- OpenCL 1.2 (GT-640)

which one happens?

Can this change with drivers?

What about OpenCL version 2.3 GPUs? Do they seem as 2.0 in OpenCL API or correctly give `3` as minor version?

If anyone could share his/hers experience, I appreciate.

---

For now, project can take 1.2 or 2.0 versions (Intel drivers I installed have an experimental version 2.1 with bugs so I filter-out with minor version checking, I'm not sure if Nvidia or Amd can do similar or opposite things in OpenCL-2.x capable cards). I can also filter for platform names "experimental"/"beta" to elliminate such platforms but I'm not sure if there are multiple versions for same GPUs.

---

I assume 2.0 devices have backwards compatilibity for 1.2 but do I need anything extra to enable 1.2 spec? For now I'm not doing anything extra for 1.2 devices. Maybe 2.0 needs some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each platform returns its own version number independently of the others. You can have a mix, for example a GPU at 1.2 and a CPU driver at 2.0.

If you make only OpenCL 1.2 API calls you can use either. If you make OpenCL 2.0 API calls you can only use 2.0 or higher platforms.

Likewise, devices within a platform can return their own version numbers, although I don't think they can be larger than their parent platform number. An example of this is an older GPU, which might only be OpenCL 1.1 even though the platform is 1.2.

Separate from this is the version of OpenCL kernel language each device supports. For backwards compatibility if you don't pass compile options you are getting OpenCL C 1.x. If you are on a 2.x device you can pass an option string when compiling your kernel to get new language features.

Comment: I just wanted 1.2 compatibility for now, and compile options are `(0,0,0)` always(maybe just some rounding options will be added later). Header filess are 1.2 so it is using 1.2 always. Then, even if it selects 2.0, it would work? (considering I managed to filter bugged experimental/beta versions). Then only remaining  job is to find all duplicated(1.2, 2.0, 2.3,...) versions of same platform and join them into one(such as picking 1.2 one)?

Comment: Great, you're using 1.2 headers which works great on 1.2 and higher devices. You don't need to filter from multiple versions of a platform; a given platform will only report once, with a single version. I was talking about if you have multiple platforms (like NVIDIA at 1.2, AMD at 2.0, and Intel at 2.1).

Comment: I wish there were free-to-use online cloud access to run github projects with multiple vendor GPUs and an FPGA and two CPUs(to see if both seen as single device or different devices, testing compiling time of FPGA and solving bugs between AMD and NVIDIA while using Intel driver versus others just for testing), similar to online C#/C++/Java compilers.